# Searching for related content

Tags: feature-request, search, related-questions

Before I reply to a question I usually use the search function of math.stackexchange to find related content. I read the FAQ, I tried both ASCII and LaTeX code, with/without tags, but nothing beats the "related content" table, which is the list the forum opens automatically to the right of the screen, as related to the main question.

The related content table is so search-strong that picks up even identical LaTeX code. I have often seen identical functions there, to the function I am looking for.

So my question is, is there any particlar way of searching which guarantees finding results as strong as those of the "related content" table? Is there perhaps a script of sorts for the search code to input on the search box to achieve this?

Apologies if this is already addressed somewhere.

Comment: As I say frequently here, this is the dream: good math search engine integration. But from what I know, there is no great way to search for math here.

Comment: I think the point of the question is that whatever search algorithm the site uses to compile the "related questions" list seems to be pretty good, so is there any way for individual users to get our hands on that code or something like it.

Comment: Meta.SE: [How are “related” questions selected?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20473/how-are-related-questions-selected) and [Related questions in “Ask Question” page is better than search tool](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/related-questions-in-ask-question-page-is-better-than-search-tool) (You will probably be able to find some more posts related to this. For example, by checking list of related questions there.)