# Why does "Similar questions" rarely ever show similar questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

While posting questions, I always make sure to write an appropriate title, explain it well, and format my questions clearly, and I always go through all the questions shown under 'Similar questions.' However, almost always, 'Similar questions' do not show any related questions which have to pointed out by other users. This affects user reputation and goodwill on the site.

The 'Similar questions' feature needs a sincere update so as to save everyone's time and avoid duplicate questions.

To exemplify, none of the questions shown under 'Similar questions' showed any related questions, which made me think this is a new question at first, but it was asked before [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34353/1052701), which, along with questions tagged in comments, have no answers.

To clarify, I reached the linked question by changing the title of my question several times. Simply changing the double quotes to single quotes from question title removes the linked question from 'Similar questions.'

Therefore, I am posting this under discussion and feature request tags.

Comment: At the same time, here are some older posts praising how well this feature works: [Trying to ask a question provides better results than normal search.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26415) and ["Maybe answered questions" box on "Ask Question" page is much more useful than "Search Q&A"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25447).

Comment: "Similar questions" usually finds other questions with words in common.  Not so much with equations in common.

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29265/how-to-search-on-this-site) for how to search this site (including for equations). These methods are much more powerful than that used by the SE "similar questions" (which is so weak that it should never be relied upon for answer / dupe searching).