# Is there a way to see related questions *before* I post a question?

Tags: feature-request, search, related-questions

Is there a way to see related questions *before* I post a question?

I recently posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4372859/expected-number-of-random-real-numbers-from-0-to-1-needed-for-their-sum-to-e). After I wrote the question, but before I posted it, I went through the automatically-generated list of "similar" questions and didn't find any matches. After I posted my question, I looked at the automatically-generated list of "related" questions on the right side and found essentially the same question. If I had seen it while writing my question, I would not have posted my question.

It would be nice if all the related questions were included in the list of similar questions.

Comment: Some related posts on this meta: [Searching for related content](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16766), [Improve similar problem searching system](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34353).
Maybe also: ["Maybe answered questions" box on "Ask Question" page is much more useful than "Search Q&A"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25447), [Question Search Feature](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16419). And on [meta.se]: [Related questions in "Ask Question" page is better than the search tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20432)

Comment: @MartinSleziak  Thanks. My question is answered by the "Improve similar problem searching system" post, specifically by Lee David Chung Lin's comment: "it actually takes some time for the system to "process" your new post in regard to establishing it's relation to existing posts... the processing time may be a few minutes, could be much longer. Occasionally one can observe in real time (via frequent refreshing) the list of related posts going from just one (or even zero), when it's basically a blank on the right hand side, up to the eventual full list of five, eight, or whatever."